# Splitting at a specific point in PDFBox

Tags: pdf, split, pdfbox

I would like to split to generate a new pdf by concatenating certain individual pages, but the last page has to be split at a certain point (i.e. all content above a limit to be included and everything below to be excluded - I only care about the ones having their upper left corner above a line). Is that possible using PDFbox?

Comment: Does it suffice if the content below that line is not visible? In that case prepending a clip path to the page content would suffice; this is fairly easy to accomplish. Or does that content have to be completely removed from the file (e.g. for security reasons)? A generic solution for that is quite a lot more difficult.

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is collect parts of several pdf files and store them with tags in a database. Then users will search these parts using the keywords and they should get back the results displayed by title. Half a page wil not have an effect on loading, but still might not be elegant. Cropping could be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve the task, i.e. to *split* a page *at a certain point (i.e. all content above a limit to be included and everything below to be excluded)* would be to prepend a clip path.

You can use this method:

```
void clipPage(PDDocument document, PDPage page, BoundingBox clipBox) throws IOException
{
    PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, false);
    pageContentStream.addRect(clipBox.getLowerLeftX(), clipBox.getLowerLeftY(), clipBox.getWidth(), clipBox.getHeight());
    pageContentStream.clipPath(PathIterator.WIND_NON_ZERO);
    pageContentStream.close();

    COSArray newContents = new COSArray();
    COSStreamArray contents = (COSStreamArray) page.getContents().getStream();
    newContents.add(contents.get(contents.getStreamCount()-1));
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.getStreamCount()-1; i++)
    {
        newContents.add(contents.get(i));
    }
    page.setContents(new PDStream(new COSStreamArray(newContents)));
}
```

to clip the given page along the given clipBox. (It first creates a new content stream defining the clip path and then arranges this stream to be the first one of the page.)

E.g. to clip the content of a page along the horizontal line 650 units above the bottom, do this:

```
PDPage page = ...
PDRectangle cropBox = page.findCropBox();
clipPage(document, page, new BoundingBox(
    cropBox.getLowerLeftX(),
    cropBox.getLowerLeftY() + 650,
    cropBox.getUpperRightX(),
    cropBox.getUpperRightY()));
```

For a running example look here: [ClipPage.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/ClipPage.java).